# Export text to excel, translate and import back

Tags: javascript, c#, scripting, adobe, adobe-indesign

As the title says, I am looking for advice on how to program an own little tool to export text from an adobe in-design file (like *.idml) to excel - translate it - and import it back to in-design with the translated text.

I saw there is a COM interface to in-design for C#. Is this doable with it? Is there any documentation on how one could do something like that or do I need to write javascript to do what I want.

I found out about the **ExportAllStories.jsx** script which is built-in inside in-design (it exports the text/stories to individual files) but I didn't find out on how I could import the files back after I would change/translate them.

Comment: What tool are you using for the translation?

Comment: The text will be translated manually in the excel (2nd column for example). The "tool" just exports and imports from and to an adobe in-design file.

Comment: The reason I was asking is that most professional translation tools will extract text from an IDML and reinsert the translation once it is done, so you may be duplicating work that has already been done for you by the software developers of these tools

Comment: I would like to create such a simple tool by my own and maybe one of the devs of these tools can provide me some infos on how I could do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. There was not really a documentation but In-Design has a .NET C# COM - Interface and I was able to access the content, like texts with that reference.